# Session values are not stored after submiting the form

Tags: php, mysql, session, cross-browser, browser

Here is my enquiry form code..the session is not stored after the form submission on IE the form is not retaining the values in google chrome it is fine..all the fields in form are emptied after submission..i only want to store values if the captcha code is incorrect..
can any one plz help

```
                <?php
                session_start();
                ob_flush();

                include("header.php");

                 if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))    
                 {

                    if ($_POST["vercode"] != $_SESSION["vercode"] OR $_SESSION["vercode"]=='')
                    { 
                        $msg="Incorrect verification code";

                        $ssubject   =   $_POST['Subject'];
                        $name       =   $_POST['name'];
                        $address    =   $_POST['address'];


                        $_SESSION['Subject']    =   $ssubject;
                        $_SESSION['name']       =   $name;
                        $_SESSION['address']    =   $address;


                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $email_to="abc@gmail.com";

                    $ssubject   =   $_POST['Subject'];
                    $name       =   $_POST['name'];
                    $address    =   $_POST['address'];


                    $to     =       $email_to;

                    $subject="Message from my Website Inquiry"." ".date("D dS M,Y h:i a");

                    $header="from: craze $email";

                    $messages= "INQUIRY\r\n\r\nSUBJECT: $ssubject\r\n\r\nNAME: $name \r\n\r\nADDRESS: $address \r\n\r";

                    $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$messages,$header);

                    if($sentmail)
                    {

                        $success="Your Contact Details Has Been Sent To Administrator Address.";
                        unset($_SESSION['Subject']);
                        unset($_SESSION['name']);
                        unset($_SESSION['address']);


                    }

                    }
                }
                ?>
                    <form id="form1"  name="email_check" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" action="">
                        <select name="Subject">
                        <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
                        <option value="Appointment Request" selected="selected">Appointment Request</option>
                        <option value="Doctors inquiry">Doctor's Inquiry</option>
                        <option value="Service Inquiry">Service Inquiry</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        </select>


                        <input name="name" class="text_box" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?>"/>
                        <textarea class="text_boxlarge" name="address"><?php echo $_SESSION['address'];?></textarea>
             <div class="namepart"><h5>Enter Code</h5></div>
        <div class="tex_part">
            <img src="captcha.php">
            <input type="text" name="vercode" 
          class="text_box" style="width:120px;margin-top:16px;" /> 
        </div>
        </div>

                        <input name="Submit"  type="image" src="images/submit_burron1.jpg"  height="20" width="54" value="Submit" />
                        <input name="cancel" type="image" src="images/reset_button.jpg" height="20" width="54" usemap="#Map2Map" />
                    </form>
```

Comment: what is exact issue your are facing. I used your code and enter wrong captcha it retained other values.

Comment: @LearnerStudent one IE the form is not retaining the values in google chrome it is fine

Comment: Have you checked if you enabled the cookies in Internet Explorer?